# How to Create Hyperlink to Uploaded files to open the file

Tags: html, css, asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

Hi Below is the code for Uploading Multiple files I cant display all the file names at a time it shows only one file name and how to create hyperlink to Uploaded documents to view the files.

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then
        Try
            FileUpload1.SaveAs("Destinationpath\testing\\" & _
               FileUpload1.FileName)
            Label1.Text = "File name: " & _
          FileUpload1.FileName & "<br>"
    ListBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))
      Catch ex As Exception
            Label1.Text = "ERROR: " & ex.Message.ToString()
        End Try
    Else
        Label1.Text = "You have not specified a file."
    End If
End Sub
 Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    'Files.RemoveAt(ListBox1.SelectedIndex)
    ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text)
    Label1.Text = "File removed"
End Sub
```

and below is the aspx code

```
    <div>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"/><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" 
     Text="Upload Document" /><br />
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
    <asp:listbox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" Width="175px"></asp:listbox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Remove" Width="98px" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
```

can anyone help me to do this. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Use ListBox for this. It will be something like:

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    foreach (HttpPostedFile fl in fu.PostedFiles)
    {
        fl.SaveAs(DestinationPath + fl.FileName);
        ListItem li = new ListItem();
        li.Text = fl.FileName;
        ListBox1.Items.Add(li);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sai if you need hyperlink also, I would like approach you to create some PANEL in your page, and then add HYPERLINK controls depending on your files. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly, how it will be on VB.NET, but I write some code to you and in should work in VB.NET. Wait a minute, I will post that as one more answer

Comment: Can we done without using listbox and how to hyperlink to the uploaded files

Comment: I have edited code can anyone please help me to create link to open the file

Answer (score 0):

In your design page:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlFiles" runat="server" />
```

Your code behind:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    For Each fl as HttpPostedFile in fu.PostedFiles
        Dim fileLink as String = DestinationPath + fl.FileName
        fl.SaveAs(fileLink)
        Dim hpr as New HyperLink
        hpr.Text = "Download file"
        hpr.NavigateUrl = fileLink
        pnlFiles.Controls.Add(hpr)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: @sai I don't use VB.NET, that's why I said, that I don't know how it will be exactly. Try to debug and see the values. But principle is correct

Comment: My code works as follows: you have a Panel control in your page. As soon as you choose files and click on Upload button, foreach loop starts work, save file and create Hyperlink control, which contain a navigate url to your file. Then hyperlink control has been added to your panel.

Comment: it shows error I was trying to debug but couldn't solve it